# Large Database Query Affecting Entire System

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

We have a Windows Application (written in .Net) that supports about 500+ users.  There is a specific function on this applications that'll bring back about 40k records (on a MS SQL Server) that gets run a handful times per day.

However, when this large query is run other users of the system seem to be 'Timing Out' which to me seems to mean that the large query is hogging server resources and causing other users not to be able to use the system properly.

I'm trying to understand how the resource allocation works because I feel like a 40k query isn't exactly massive but is decently sizable.

Our application architecture is UI -> Service Layer -> Web Service -> Database

Could it be the Web service that is causing the issue or could my query possibly be 'locking' the SQL database and not letting other users interact with it?

The SQL query is pretty straight forward, it literally selects all records from a specific table (this table houses data that is extracted from other tables and is about 40k records right now, there are about 50 columns in the table):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
```

Is pretty much the query.  There are no joins and I'm using a stored procedure.

Comment: Probably the latter, your query is hogging the database server. Can you show us the query and related table structure? Or maybe an execution plan? It could also be that the query is returning a very large result set causing the web server to spike in memory usage.

Comment: What does you query look like? How many tables is it affecting? Does it have lots of joins? Can you use a view instead of working with the tables directly? Can you use a stored procedure? Can you cache the result?

Comment: How long does it take to execute this query and return all records in SSMS?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn There are no writes in the query.  It's literally "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

Comment: @TimLehner It took me 22 seconds to pull back 39,471 rows in SSMS.

Comment: 22 seconds is still slow for that many rows i'd say. Is there any indexing on the table?

Comment: I meant writes to that table from any other source that could take place at the same time that this query is active.

Comment: Are some of your columns very large e.g images?

Comment: The only large column is a varchar(max) for a 'Narrative' field.

Comment: Can you run the statement and get the execution plan in SSMS and put the image in the question?  Just so we can have a look to see if there is anything unexpected in there...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have enough information to say anything definitive, but I can make a couple guesses/suggestions.

First, if there are no writes into this table... from any source... while the query is active, you might improve things by adding a `with (nolock)` hint to that select. Again: only do this if the table is remains unchanged during the query, or if you're comfortable with this query producing results that are stale/wrong because of a dirty read.

Also, the phrase "pretty much" in your description of the query indicates that there might be *something* else that we're not seeing; it's still simple, but it's something. If that something is an ORDER BY clause, making the order match with the primary key (or aligning the primary key with the order you need) would likely help as well.

As for the web service layer vs database as the bottleneck, this should be pretty easy to determine. If it's the web service, you'll know because CPU, RAM, or network I/O would spike to 100% on the server for the service layer, drowning out other clients. Possibly it is the service, because the service network layer has to process all your data twice: once as it pulls it down from the database, and again as it re-transmits it to the end user clients. So there is a small multiplier effect for it's data use. But even with that effect, I think the database is the more likely culprit.

A final suggestion is that if it's okay for this data to be stale, you might try adding code to your service layer to cache it.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I apologize because I think I misunderstood.  There are writes to the table, just not in the query to pull the data.  I apologize for the confusion.  If you use with (nolock) would that cause an exception if a write was attempted during the query?

Comment: No, but it might cause you to return unexpected data.

Answer (score 1):

If you do select * from MyTable it's going to lock the table so everybody else has to wait.

First thing to check - in your code, how are you reading the records? If you are using a datareader, it will lock the table until you close it. Use a SQLDataAdapter and put it into a table. That will only leave the table locked for the time it takes actually pull the data.

Another thing is the die hards will say don't do a * on the pull. Only pull the fields you need.

If you don't mind having 'dirty' data (non-committed) do a select * from mytable with (nolock). That means that it will get anything that hasn't been committed yet. But if the tables is not changing constantly, that should be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

40k rows x 50 columns is huge amount of data to be extracting on a real-time system with 500+ users. Let's say the average column size of those 50 columns is 20 bytes then you are retrieving approx 800k of data, but if you have many varchar's 100's of bytes long then that size is going to bump up considerably.

I would question why you need such a huge query, it's obviously too much data for someone to comfortably view on screen. If it's a data extraction to feed some other data store then consider only running out-of-office hours or have a process that extracts it in batches in the background or replicate the data to a separate server.

Comment: 800K over an internal LAN is nothing.

Comment: Yeah it's for a data extraction, not something users are pulling up to view as a 'live query'.

Comment: @Joel Coelhoorn although not a problem for the LAN itself when the data is being served onto the LAN by a server already dealing with large number of processing and I/O requests it could be significant. Also 800k may be a conserative figure.